# Avoiding repetition when tikz node name and label are identical

Tags: tikz-pgf

If a tikz node is to be named and labelled identically, is there a version of

```
\node (some text) {some text};
```

without the repetition?

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps do something like the following code. Note that when using `node contents` the parsing of the node stops after `[]`, so you have to use `\node [..., at={(x,y)}]` instead of `\node [...] at (x,y)` if you want to place it at a specific coordinate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  namelabel/.style={
    name=#1,
    node contents=#1
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [namelabel=some label];
\node [namelabel=foobar,right=of some label];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can of course use a shorter key name, e.g. `nl` instead of `namelabel`, to make it quicker to write.